# UserControl OnMouseWheel fires but other events do not

Tags: c#

I have some basic override code in the same class to catch mouse events. I can get OnMouseWheel to fire, but other click events do to not fire with the same code.

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine("mouse down"); //does not work
} 

protected override void OnMouseWheel(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine("mouse wheel"); //works
}
```

Does OnMouseWheel need focus to fire? That has been what I have been trying to troubleshoot so far.

Comment: In Windows the wheel events are sent to the control with input focus, not the control that the mouse is over.

Comment: In that case the control with input focus is what I want the other mouse events to run on too, but it does not detect them.

Comment: Mouse Down should happen regardless of focus; are you sure you attached the handler to the control instance correctly?

Comment: I just noticed that you are overriding the function instead of attaching a handler.  Depending on how you do this, you may not get proper event flow.  For instance, overriding MouseDown, and not calling the base or  raising the event may cause future events that depend on the overridden event to stop working, I would reccomend always calling the base class implementation unless you know for sure you don't want its default behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnMouseClick ( MouseEventArgs e )
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Mouse click"); //works
}

private void panel1_MouseClick ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    OnMouseClick(e);
}
```

In your actual design window make sure you attached the event to the Control. If you need to do it programatically, then

[image: Event]

```
this.panel1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseClick);
```

**Note:**
Yes I know the control names aren't the exact same and you aren't using MetroControls, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the base method implementation of OnMouse events so the base class can react to the events:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnMouseDown");
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnMouseUp");
    base.OnMouseUp(e);
}
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnMouseWheel");
    base.OnMouseWheel(e);
}
```